# How is category theory relevant to fractal geometry?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, fractals

In [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/3Du7rLvP_wI?t=150) by Richard Southwell at the 2:30 timestamp, it is said that:

> Fractal geometry can be studied quite profitably using category theory.

The fields seem very different to me but I am not very familiar with either field. I don't see how the study of composition in category theory would apply to the study of fractals, other than for specific types such as IFS fractals...

Googling this statement and searching stack exchange, I can't find any results that link the two fields.

So, how are fractals studied using category theory?

Comment: You can [ask them](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/666875/richard-southwell) directly @Richard Southwell

Comment: @FShrike I have no way to contact him. Mentioning with an @ will not alert a user to a post they have not commented in, and there is no way to directly message someone on this site.

Comment: there is. Chat, but also commenting under their posts

Comment: Oh, ok. I had thought comments like that would not be allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might initially look implausible that there's a connection, I agree. After all, as Tom Leinster so nicely puts it in his lovely book, category theory “takes a bird’s eye view of mathematics. From high in the sky, details become invisible, but we can spot patterns that were impossible to detect from ground level.” And you might suppose that the study of fractal geometry is mostly about just those fine details which become invisible at the level of category theory. Just look, for example, at the fine detail of the theorems about Julia sets in Barnsley's *Fractals Everywhere*.

But ...

But then fractals arise from self-similarities; and self-similarity seems on second thoughts to be the kind of high-level idea which might after all lend itself to some sort of category theoretic treatment. OK we might not get at some of the nitty-gritty theorems that way but we might get some higher-level results. And so we find, ahah, that there is indeed e.g. an interesting paper by none other than Tom Leinster about Self-Similarity, mentioning Julia sets and more, which brings categorial ideas to bear. [See here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4474.pdf).  ....

Comment: Thank you, the paper you link is very interesting. Determining the uniqueness of a self-similar object is a very interesting application of category theory.
Also, your Logic Study Guide has really helped me out, so thank you again!

Comment: *Some* fractals arise from self-similarity.  Not all (probably not even "most"; probably not even a set of positive measure).  I have had a *lot* of conversations with category theorists about applications to the study of fractals, and have, overall, not been very impressed with what they can say.  Category theory and fractal geometry are on nearly opposite ends of a spectrum---fractal geometry is all about the weird and *specific* pathologies of sets, while category theory tries to smooth that all away.

Comment: Having spent some time skimming through Leinster's paper, I don't think that what he is doing has much to do with fractals.  Rather, he is taking some of the tools which are sometimes used in the study of fractals, and using them to build objects in a category theoretic framework.  I don't think that he is saying much about fractals (nor is he trying to, I think), but rather taking inspiration from a small part of the field which studies fractals.

Comment: It looks interesting, but I don't think that this approach is going to be useful for answering the kinds of questions that are typically asked about fractals.  Which is cool, since, again, I don't think that Leinster is really trying to answer those kinds of questions.  It just isn't the goal.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, that all sounds about right to me! (Oh, and  I didn't mean to imply that all fractals arise from self-similarity.) As my first para and your similar "opposite ends of spectrum" remark suggest, there is surely not much to be expected from category theory by way of answering nitty-gritty questions about fractals. I just thought it (initially) rather surprising and then intriguing to find *any* tenuous connections being made!

Comment: Indeed.  And the paper looks kind of interesting.  I've now managed to skim through most of it, and there are a couple of sections which I think might bear a second reading (the discussion of walks feels somewhat close to something that I am interested in).